# Custom transition button fade

Tags: swift, animation, swift3

I’ve been trying to fix this for eight days now. I ripped out everything to do with transitions and put it in it’s own basic project: https://github.com/matthijsotterloo/CustomTransitions

I’m trying to create an experience when you open the app to the MainViewController (yellow with a label) and then can swipe pages on top of that. When a view swipes into place I want to fade out the button on MainViewController interactively. For context, in the actual app MainViewController shows 3 monkeys a fact, and two buttons (see screenshot below). I’m trying to make those fade from 1 to 0 opacity without changing the camera view and without moving the button (only animating opacity).

Things I’ve learned:
- Added SwipeablePresentationController.swift in an attempt to change shouldRemovePresentersView so that the presentingViewController is not removed when a ViewController is laid on top.
- SwipeableTransitionSlideAnimator falls back to toViewController.view because iOS seems to have bugs with transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) not working sometimes.
- I add the toViewController to transitionContext.containerView but not the fromViewController because the docs say it’s already added and apple doesn’t anywhere in their sample code. Also, I think adding it breaks gesture recognizers.
- Since MainViewController is always shown, I never call beginAppearanceTransition on it (viewWill/Did/Disappear/Load)
- I have tried various hacks adding the View Controller to the window in the animation completion block. This fixes some bugs but when a new view controller is presented modal fullScreen, iOS doesn’t seem to remember the stack order of the views after that view controller is dismissed.

I think something I’m missing is around:
- Adding the view controller to the window manually after animations.
- Properly calling beginAppearanceTransition.
- Correctly configuring the PresentationController,
- Not removing the fromView from it’s super view because that will disable the UIGestureRecognizer mid-swipe.

But not sure what it is! I know this is a lot but I’ve tried everything I can think of and would really appreciate any ideas any of you will have.